# How to fetch the description from the backend and display it in a textarea when editing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a web application in React where users can create and edit notes. I'm facing a specific issue when trying to display the description of a note in the  component while editing.

The structure of my application is as follows: I have a Node.js backend that provides the note data through a RESTful API, and I'm using React to build the user interface.

When editing an existing note, I need to display the current description of the note in the text field of the `<textarea>`. However, I'm having difficulties in getting the description of the note from the backend and placing it in the `<textarea>`.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```html
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { api } from "../../services";

function UpdateNote() {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNote() {
      const response = await api.get("/notes/1"); // Example: Getting note with ID 1
      const note = response.data;

      // How can I display the note's description in the textarea?
      // I've tried using both `defaultValue` and `value`, but they didn't work.

      setDescription(note.description);
    }

    fetchNote();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}></textarea>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UpdateNote;
```

I've tried using both the defaultValue and value properties of the `<textarea>`, but neither worked for displaying the note's description.

I would like to know how I can fetch the description of the note from the backend and display it in the `<textarea>` when editing the note. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When putting text into a textarea, it goes inside the textarea tags like `<textarea>Text you want to show up in text area</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Put the value you want to display as a child of the `textarea` tags..

```
<textarea>{description}</textarea>
```